# (Dagger 2) Provide same instance for different types in MVP

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-mvp

I'm following MVP pattern in my application. I have a view which extends another abstract view class, implements another interface (say A) and also implements View contract (say B) in MVP. I want to have a same instance in dependency graph when I ask for types A and B. How can I achieve that ?

In short:

```
class MyAbstractView implements MyInterface {

}

class MyView extends MyAbstractView implements MyViewContract {

}

@Module
class MyModule {
    @Provides
    MyInterface provideMyInterface() {
     return new MyView();
    }

    @Provides
    MyViewContract provideMyViewContract() {
       // I cannot call provideMyInterface() and return here
       // but I want to return the same MyView instance
       // ????
   }
}
```

Note: I dont want to have MyView and persist it in the @Module!!

Comment: Have you checked the @Named annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use constructor injection along with the `@Binds` annotation in your module to achieve this. Simply add a constructor and annotate it with `@Inject` in `MyView`. You can then mark `MyView` as `@Singleton` so that the same instance is used everywhere(assuming the component is also scoped with `@Singleton`).

```
@Singleton
class MyView extends MyAbstractView implements MyViewContract {
    @Inject
    public MyView() {}
}

@Module
abstract class MyModule {
    @Binds
    abstract MyInterface provideMyInterface(MyView myView);

    @Binds
    abstract MyViewContract provideMyViewContract(MyView myView);
}
```

Comment: Solved my problem !!